# Reference to enum is ambiguous objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, enums

I defined a NS_ENUM below in another file:

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSUInteger, LinkPlatformType){
    LinkPlatformTypeEmail = 1,
    LinkPlatformTypeFacebook,
    LinkPlatformTypeGoogle
};
```

When I try to do a switch case:

```
- (void)linkWithType:(LinkPlatformType)linkType {
    switch (linkType) {
        case LinkPlatformTypeGoogle:
            break;
        case LinkPlatformTypeFacebook:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I am getting a build error: `Reference to LinkPlatformTypeGoogle is ambiguous`. `Reference to LinkPlatformTypeFacebook is ambiguous`.

Updates:

The file defines.h which i defined the enum is in for example Target 1, And there is a Class StoreClass which import this defines.h file. And the StoreClass.m Target Membership I have set as multiple targets: Target 1 and Target 2. So after I do this, the `Reference to LinkPlatformTypeFacebook is ambiguous` appeared. Will this be the reason?

Comment: Did you try with a different naming for the enum? My best guess it's that it might be just a naming conflict and the compiler does not know what to reference.

Comment: I tried the same code as yours with new project..I'm not getting any error as such, just to verify have you import file? and yes I put the NS_ENUM in defines.h file which is header file.

Comment: @Vlad I checked twice. There is no naming conflict. I only defined one in my project.

Comment: @RahulShirphule I did import the file otherwise it will be another kind of warning.

Comment: Maybe try to go through all three possible value in the switch, you just handled 2 out of three (although I see you have the default there) ...

Comment: @Vlad I did go through all the value in switch. Still the same error.

Comment: can you please show us how do you invoke `linkWithType:` method?

Comment: @x4h1d Sure. `[[LinkHelper sharedHelper] linkWithType:LinkPlatformTypeGoogle]`;

Comment: my best guess is, you have multiple imports of  `defines.h` file. Try moving that ENUM definition to `LinkHelper` class only.

Comment: @x4h1d There are many places that I need the enum. If I move the enum definition to a class only. It will not work.

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378474/reference-to-x-is-ambiguous

Comment: When you need that ENUM you will also need this `LinkHelper` class too, right? so you can define it here. Or find a common class to import `defines.h`.

Comment: @Anupam I tried. Not helping.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199442/reference-to-is-ambigous-error-in-xcode/41765279#41765279

Answer (score 6):

Changing the import from

```
#import "SwipeView.h"
```

to

```
@import SwipeView;
```

worked for me

Comment: My class was in a module (subproject) so I tried to import @import MainModule.Folder where my view lives instead of the .h implementation and it worked, thank you!

Comment: It works for me with FBSDKLoginManager in FBSDKCoreKit 4.28.0