# Xcode: "Reference to NSString is ambiguous"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I don't understand how such a thing can happen: I have created an Xcode project (Xcode 6) and I imported some files from a previous project (a Storyboard, the Images.xcassets file and some .h and .m files)

Now when I import some of those headers in my code, each line using a NSString reports the error "Reference to NSString is ambiguous".

Is this a known issue, how to solve that?

Comment: What are you `#import`ing?

Comment: @trojanfoe Some .h files that come from my previous project.

Comment: No, I want to know what system headers you are importing.

Comment: @trojanfoe`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>`

Comment: What have you tried to do to resolve this? At the very least hold down the option key and choose Product > Clean Build Folder…

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199442/reference-to-is-ambigous-error-in-xcode/41765279#41765279

Answer (score 0):

Reason: **Engineering Index is broken, Rebuild index**

Workaround: Xcode -> Window -> Organizer -> select the project, find Derived Data, click on the back of Delete, and then restart XCode can.

Comment: That solved the issue for about a minute but it appeared again. Same thing happen when I clean the project.

Comment: 1. Clean the project              
2. Deleting everything inside '~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/' (if button inside the organizer window did not work)
3. Clean once more
4. Build project