# Reference to 'XYZ' is ambiguous using pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

After Research on this issue I didn't get any solution for that. 
I followed below link but didn't find solution to resolve issue -
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378474/reference-to-x-is-ambiguous)

I am facing issue - Reference to 'XYZ' is ambiguous. when I am importing module within multiple classes.
Anyone can please help me to resolve this issue. I wand to import module within two classes.

I am using Pod to install module

Comment: Could you paste here the contents of your podfile?

Comment: target “Demo” do
use_frameworks!
  pod 'AKMusicPlayer', :git => 'git@git.assembla.com:enterprise-component-repository.git', :branch => 'iOS-Components'
end

Comment: Created private pod.

Comment: are you sure the `AKMusicPlayer` doesn't provide some of the classes that you already have in the project?